# tfdbg > "run -f has_inf_or_nan" doesn't seem to work (NaN loss during training)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tf.contrib.learn to fit a model and I'm encountering `tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.`

When I try to debug, the debugger doesn't let me inspect what's happening during that error. Instead, the exception is raised. My code looks like this:

```
debug_hook = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook()
debug_hook.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan", tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan)
hooks = [debug_hook]
...
classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs,
               steps=hyper_params['training_steps'],
               monitors=hooks)
```

The debug command used is

```
run -f has_inf_or_nan
```

Tensorflow 1.1. Windows 10. Python 3.5. My input data is of shape [600] with values in the range [0, 1] (inclusive). Starting with a 10000 sample subset of my dataset. I'm trying to predict 3000 output classes.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: What exception did you get?

Comment: tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.

Comment: This is a bug fixed recently in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/38249d6be21e77bbd0663b71af598c0bdb99d6dc. The fix is already available in the master branch and nightly builds of tensorflow. So either use nightly artifacts (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation) or wait for the next release.

Comment: Also, from your profile, I see that you are at Google. The fix corresponds to internal change list 158310249.

Comment: Great, thanks! I ended up discovering the underlying problem with my code and solved the Nan problem, but it's good to know that the debugger is fixed for everyone in the future.